# Formatting SQL queries in MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I am trying to use an SQL query in Access. I have had this issue before but still do not fully understand what I am doing wrong. I am trying to run a strSQL statement in MS Access, however it is giving me a "Too few paramters - expected 1" error when I try to run the code.

```
Sub SampleReadCurve()

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
Dim strSQL As String
Dim CurveID As Long
Dim MarkRunID As Long
Dim ZeroCurveID As String

CurveID = 15

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & CurveID & "ORDER BY MaturityDate"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)

[...]
```

I want to select from a table in Access, VolatilityOutput, for all instances in which CurveID = 15. What is wrong with the way I have used strSQL?

Comment: **[Possible SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** You should bind parameters instead of concatenating SQL query.

Comment: I think you need an extra space in `" ORDER BY MaturityDate"`.  Note the space after the initial quote.  But also, what @lad2025 said...  use parameters instead.

Comment: As you have it written, your SQL statement will look like this:
SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput 
WHERE CurveID=15ORDER BY MaturityDate

As Hambone observed, you need a space between the " and the last of your statement.

Comment: if i reformat it as :  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & CurveID & " ORDER BY MaturityDate" the same error occurs, is there something else in the syntax that could be causing an error?

Comment: The error message makes it sound like you have declared a parameter somewhere but you haven't assigned it a value.  Is there any other code you have omitted for the sake of brevity that might be relevant?

Comment: Add `Debug.Print strSQL` to the line before `Set rs =`, then run the code.  Go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g will take you there), copy the statement text, and paste it into SQL View of a new query in the Access query designer.  When you attempt to run the query, Access will display an input dialog for you to enter the parameter's value, and that dialog also includes the parameter name.  What is the parameter name?

Comment: The parameter name given by the input dialog is CurveID, and when i input "15" into the box, the query runs correctly

Comment: Access does not find a field named `CurveID` in your `VolatilityOutput` table.  Double-check the spelling of that field name.  If the table is a actually a link to a SQL Server table, delete that link and recreate it.

Comment: ah perfect that was exactly it - thank you so much

Comment: a followup question: currently it is ordering by MaturityDate. if I also wanted to order by MarkAsofDate in addition, how would I format this?
I tried to add a separate line strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY MarkAsofDate" but was unsuccessful

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I can repeat your error message if I declare a parameter and don't assign it:

```
strSQL = "parameters [CID] number; " & _
   "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID=" & CurveID & " ORDER BY MaturityDate"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)
```

Gives me the same thing you are reporting:

> Too Few Parameters.  Expected 1

I think you might be able to kill two birds with one stone here -- fix your error and use parameters, the way several on this thread are suggesting.  This is an example of how you would invoke the parameter:

```
Sub SampleReadCurve()

  Dim rs As Recordset
  Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim CurveID As Long
  Dim MarkRunID As Long
  Dim ZeroCurveID As String
  Dim qry As QueryDef

  CurveID = 15

  strSQL = "parameters [CID] number; " & _
     "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE CurveID = [CID] ORDER BY MaturityDate"

  Set qry = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("GetCurve", strSQL)
  qry.Parameters("CID") = CurveID
  Set rs = qry.OpenRecordset

  CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete ("GetCurve")

End Sub
```

Bear in mind this creates the query definition and clobbers it each time the sub runs, which is not best practice.  I would change this to declare the query ahead of time (through normal Access, not VBA) and invoke it within the sub, leaving it there for the next time you need it:

```
Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("GetCurve")
```

As a final note, among the numerous advantages of using the bind variable / parameter are that datatypes are managed.  This means if CurveID was a date or a string, this methodology would still work.  You would not need to change the SQL to include quotes or do any special handling for date formats -- the bind variables take care of that for you.  This means if your string was:

```
I'd like to say "hello"
```

(both single and double quotes), there would be no special handling required.  Pretty awesome, right?